# Create conditional an object on stack?

Tags: c++

What is the easiest way to create an object on stack based on a certain condition within the current scope?

Assume my current code is:

```
Base obj();
obj.print();
```

Now I want to change the code to 'plugin' a different derived class e.g. :

```
bool doBase=true;
doBase ? Base obj() : Derived obj();
obj.print();
```

But this of course does not work?

I know how to get this working, e.g. with an `if`, however my `print` in this example is in real world say 10-50 lines so this result in code duplication. Another approach is dynamically creating the objects, but I am curious there is a way to fix this without dynamically creating the objects.

```
bool doBase=true;
if (doBase) { 
  Base obj();
  obj.print();
} else { 
  Derived obj();
  obj.print(); // CODE DUPLICATION
}
```

Full snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "In base"<<std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "In derived"<<std::endl; }
};

int main() {
   bool doBase=true;
   doBase ? Base obj() : Derived obj();
   obj.print();
   doBase=false;
   doBase ? Base obj2() : Derived obj2();
   obj2.print();
}
```

Comment: "however my print in this example is in real world say 10-50 lines so this result in code duplication"  place that 10-50 lines in a virtual function and its again the same as your simple `print` example

Comment: Side note, `Base obj();` does not create an object of type `Base`

Comment: `doBase ? Base{}.print() : Derived{}.print();`?

Comment: Or, for longer persistence, use `std::variant`.

Comment: You can't. Derived classes cannot be assigned to variables of the base class type. If you need to do things with subclasses, you have to hide behind a layer of indirection, usually either a reference `Base&` or a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<Base>`). Old code will also use raw pointers (`Base*`), but that's not recommended nowadays unless there's no other option.

Comment: Code like this is usually a red flag of the OO design.  Usually, the client code just needs a pointer or reference to the base class (not necessarily base object) and then call the virtual `print` method.  What would this `main` look like if you had 10 different implementations of `print`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambdas to wrap the repetitive code, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "In base"<<std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "In derived"<<std::endl; }
};

int main() {
   auto print = [](Base &&obj){ obj.print(); };
   auto doIt = [&print](bool doBase) { doBase ? print(Base{}) : print(Derived{}); };

   doIt(true);
   doIt(false);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/lX6AZa)

Alternatively, use `std::variant`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "In base"<<std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "In derived"<<std::endl; }
};

int main() {

   auto print = [](Base& obj){ obj.print(); };
   auto doIt = [&print](bool doBase) {
      std::variant<Base, Derived> v;
      if (doBase) {
         v = Base{};
      } else {
         v = Derived{};
      }
      std::visit(print, v);
   };

   doIt(true);
   doIt(false);

   return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/fSkNU8oF8)